# Matlab - Odeset - Odeplot

Tags: matlab, ode

I would like to use odeplot so stepwise get the result instead of plotting the result afterwards. I've tried to write it like this but I can't get it to work so I would appreciate some help.

```
%Parameters

s = 1; 

q = 1; 

w = 0.1610;

y0 = [30 1 30]; % Initial values

tspan = [0 10]; % Time 0<t<10

plot=odeset('OutputFcn','odeplot');

[t, y] = ode45(@(t,y) concentration(t, y, s, q, w), plot, tspan, y0);
```

Comment: Did may answer end up helping you [solve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your output function via an ODE Options argument:

```
options = odeset('OutputFcn', @odeplot);
[t, y] = ode45(@(t,y)concentration(t, y, s, q, w), tspan, y0, options);
```

Of course you can make your own custom output function. Type `edit odeplot` to see what is required (much simpler functions are possible). Also check out `odephas2` and `odephas3`.